# Need to loop again depending on a condition javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Hi I'm making a javascript script which now is getting really hard to edit, and hard to understand for other people, I'll put it here hoping someone can understand it and give some advice or help

```
function fetchMember(id, select, sitename, total) {
    return function() {
        progress();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "script.php",
            data: $("#fetch").serialize() + "&id=" + id,
            success: function(data) {
                isUser = ($(data).text().indexOf("Invalid User") == -1);
                if (isUser) {
                    username = $(data).find(".normal").text();
                    saved = id - invalid;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "save.php",
                        data: {'username': username},
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#test").append(id+" "+data + "<br />");
                            select.text(sitename+"("+saved+"/"+total+")"); //Updating numbers of fetched profiles on the frontend
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                invalid++; //loop again here because a user wan't valid
                progress();
            }
        });
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < members; i++) {
            fetched++;
            setTimeout(fetchMember(fetched, select, sitename, total), wait*i);
        }
```

basically what I need to do is to loop again if at the end of the operation there are some invalid users, any help is really appreciated

Comment: Little advice - you can separate all those anonymous functions as named functions. Also "done-fail-always" callback look prettier and shorter, see the official docs on jQuery AJAX. It will make your code less nested and easier to understand.

Comment: What is `progress()`? What is that `setTimeout` good for? How does `invalid++` trigger another loop? Or is that what you have problems with - if so, what function should be repeated?

Comment: @Bergi progress() is just a function to animate a progress bar nothing important i can put it here if you want, seTimeout is needed to put a required interval of 800ms between ajax connections (to have responses ordered) or even more than 800ms if set by the user. invalid++ is to keep track of how many invalid user the script has found, I think I'll need that to repeat the fetchmember function depending on how many users were invalid. I hope I've been clear enough thanks for your help

Comment: @AntonMelnikov Thanks for your suggestions! How would I go for the first one? For example here instead of this <code>success: function(data) {</code>
I can use <code>.done(namedfunc(data));</code>

Comment: @AndreaScanu: "to have responses ordered" is just what I feared, and it won't work - ajax can easily take much longer or much shorter than 800ms. "I'll need that to repeat the fetchmember function depending on how many users were invalid" - you mean you only want to try again for those members that were invalid? Or wait until all fetches are done, and then fetch all again based on a condition?

Comment: I know that but it's not just that, the user can set in a form the time between a connection and another. This is important because there will be like 10000 connections and the user doesn't want to make them too fast to prevent server overloading. The default value of 800ms is to have results almost ordered, sometimes it happens that one result is received before one but I don't mind about that it's still better than having casual order. So unfortunately I'll have to keep settimeout. However what I need to do is basically that the script loops until it has n valid users, not n users

Comment: For example let's say the user want to fetch 100 members, the loop executes 100 times but there may be like 50 invalid members and the script may return only 50 valid members instead of 100. I don't want that I want to loop until 100 valid members are found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this code would help you, though it's not completely adapted for your case and wasn't tested. The main principle is the recursive call of `memberFetch` function. No need for timeouts in this case - it won't make any new requests to the server until it got a response for the last one. Feel free to ask any questions, but please try to experiment yourself :)

```
var currentId = 0; // Current member id
var membersNum = 10; // There are 10 members from 0 to 9
var neededValidUsersNum = 5; // We need only 5 valid users...
var valudUsersNum = 0; // ... but now we have 0 of them

// Let's make an array of all possible id's
// It will be a queue - we will try to fetch the first id
// In case of success - save data, remove that id from the queue, fetch the nex one
// Otherwise - put it at the back of the queue to try it again later
var possibleIds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < membersNum; i++) {
    possibleIds.push(i);
}

// Fetched user data storage
var userData = {};

function fetchMember(id) {
    var data = "some data";

    $.post('script.php', data)
        .done(function(responseData){
            onFetchMemberDone(id, responseData);
        })
        .fail(function(){
            onFetchMemberFail(id);
        });
}

function onFetchMemberDone(id, responseData){
    // Save recieved user data
    userData[id] = responseData;
    // Bump valid users num
    valudUsersNum++;
    // If there are not enough valid users - lets continue:
    if (valudUsersNum < neededValidUsersNum) { 
        // Remove valide user from the queue (it was the first one)
        possibleIds.shift();
        // try to fetch the next one
        var nextPossibleId = possibleIds[0];
        fetchMember(nextPossibleId);
    }
}

function onFetchMemberFail(id){
    // add failed user to the end of the queue
    possibleIds.push(id);
    // try to fetch the next one
    var nextPossibleId = possibleIds[0];
    fetchMember(nextPossibleId);
}

// Lets launch the cycle! It doesn't look like one because it works through recursive calls
onFetchMember(0);
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks you very much for your big help, I'll play with this in one day and let you know how it goes, I don't love that it won't start an ajax connection until one is finished because this will make the script slower but I think I'll have to go with this. Thank you :)

Comment: And furthermore I'll lose the time interval between each connection set by the user. But if this is the only way to do it I think I'll have to end up with this

Comment: Actually you can wrap `fetchMember` with `setTimeout` in `done` and `fail` callback functions, although I think it's not that necessary.

Comment: I also made another question much clearer question about this problem, you can check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569396/